# Good evening, I can not solve this problem some ideas please

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, tomcat8

> GRAVE: Erreur lors de la configuration de la classe d'écoute de l'application (application listener) [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1185)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:546)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4692)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5236)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi1rV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Put the stack frame in a quote block; that will make it a lot easier to read:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
  at ...
```

But, this is basically the web module class loader not finding the spring framework class ContextLoaderListener.  The first step is to locate the class in your environment, either as a class of the web module (it would be in one of the JAR files under WEB-INF/lib), or a class in the application library folder (within the enclosing EAR under lib), or available as a shared library, or generally made available by the server environment.

If you can't find the class, then it (or rather, the JAR which contains it) will need to be added to the application.  If you can find the class, then you'll have to look at application and server deployment information to determine if the JAR containing the class is provided properly to the web module.